# QuestPdf column row value on next page

Tags: c#

I have a problem with table generated in QuestPdf lib on my .net core web app - for a simple example i have a table with several columns: A (One line text), B(Very large text), C(One line text) - when row is split into next page, value from A and C column is duplicated. Is there any setting to disable text duplicating on table column in QuestPdf?

I tried to find the answer in the official documentation but unfortunately I couldn't find the solution.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.ShowOnce()` in the cells you don't want to be repeated.
Assuming a 3 columns table, you could use the following definition:

```
column.Item().PaddingTop(10).Table(table =>
{
    static IContainer CellStyle(IContainer container) => container.Border(1);
    table.ColumnsDefinition(columns =>
    {
        columns.RelativeColumn();
        columns.RelativeColumn();
        columns.RelativeColumn();
    });
    table.Cell().Element(CellStyle).ShowOnce().Text("Column A - One line text");
    table.Cell().Element(CellStyle).ShowOnce().Text("Column B - Very large text");
    table.Cell().Element(CellStyle).ShowOnce().Text("Column C - One line text");
});
```

More information in the docs: https://www.questpdf.com/api-reference/show-once.html